# Thins board as MQTTT Broker

Tags: thingsboard, thingsboard-gateway

If I was using thinsboard.cloud then I was putting MQTT broker name as thingsboard.cloud . But as of now I have deployed things board at GKE so what MQTT broker I can use to communicate. I tried to put public Ip address of the same but not working

Comment: What do you mean by GKE?

Comment: Google Kubernetes engine

Answer (score 0):

The Public IP Address should be correct. Unless you changed it, the default port for MQTT in ThingsBoard is 1883.

Probably there are network restrictions, which not allow you to make connections via MQTT port 1883.

Comment: I have followed all the required steps. But not able to establish connection .  I have implemented mqtt transport yml file and took it's external ip as a broker but same error is coming.